# Wordpress WooSlider arrows broken at 100%?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, slider, zooming

First of all I'm on a MacBook 15" Retina display. Working on this site and I'm noticing that when I view a page with a slider enabled at 100% on Chrome the arrows are broken (two left facing arrows positioned in the wrong place) see screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

Here's a link to the page as well: [site link](http://wildlifepress.com/sub-culture/)

When I go down to 90% zoom, or shrink the browser window down enough, the arrows look fine and centered as should be. I'm worried that this will translate over broken on other displays as well, is there anything I can adjust in the css to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes. Arrows are borked in Wooslider**. Besides, using an image this big for such tiny arrows is... *wrong*?. There are much better ways to draw arrows (SVGs, fonts, icons). Even this solution (using images) would be acceptable if the file was kept to a minimum (some 100px × 50px - perhaps less). But this one has 1000px × 600px for only 2 tiny arrows. Mindblowing).

Well, ranting aside, this will fix your arrows on widths between 769px and 1260px. I don't know why Wooslider uses 768px/769px as responsiveness breaking point while most other responsive frameworks use 767px/768px, but this is the plugin author's choice (just don't use Wooslider with Bootstrap):

```
@media (max-width: 1260px) and (min-width: 769px) {
  .wooslider .wooslider-direction-nav a {
    top: 50%;
    background: url('/wp-content/plugins/wooslider/assets/images/nav_arrows-3.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-top: 15%;
  }
  .wooslider .wooslider-direction-nav .wooslider-next {
    background-position: 100% 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

---

As a sidenote, you should wrap your jQuery scripts in

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    // your code here

});
```

A few jQuery scripts in your page are throwing an error because of this and, obviously, they don't work.